# Post selected value(s) (via Javascript) from a table to classic ASP

Tags: javascript, select, html-table

I have a table with Javascript to select rows:

```
$("#job_list tr").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('selected');    
var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
background-color: brown;
color: #FFF;
}
```

and in each "job list" row, I have a input type hidden like this:

```
<input type=hidden name=id>
```

now what I have to do, so when this form submits to my next page, I can catch all the selected row value (which is "id"), because now when I hit submit, my next page catches ALL values from ALL rows, instead of just the one I selected.

(All these pages are Classic ASP)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: because now when i hit submit, my next page catches ALL values from ALL rows, instead of just the one I selected.

Comment: Submitting an ASP page posts all the form contents. You are going to have to check for a selected value on the POSTed to ASP page.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#job_list tr").click(function(){
        //Toggle the class on click.
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        
        //If the row is "selected" then append '|s' to the input value.
        //Otherwise, remove any trailing '|s'.
        var input = $(this).find('input:first');
        var v = input.val();
        
        input.val(v.replace(/\|s$/,'') + ($(this).hasClass('selected') ? '|s' : ''));
    });
});
```

```css
.selected {
background-color: brown;
color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="job_list">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Apple</td><td>Horse</td><td>Yard<input type="hidden" name="rowselected" value="12" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Apple</td><td>Horse</td><td>Yard<input type="hidden" name="rowselected" value="22" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Apple</td><td>Horse</td><td>Yard<input type="hidden" name="rowselected" value="234" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Apple</td><td>Horse</td><td>Yard<input type="hidden" name="rowselected" value="999" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Apple</td><td>Horse</td><td>Yard<input type="hidden" name="rowselected" value="" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

I am appending '|s' to the input value for each selected row.

On the server side, you can loop through all the inputs, and check each value. If the value ends with '|s', then that row was selected.

Comment: thx. and what if i have custom value for each row? for example: 
row 1: <input type=hidden name=id value=257>
row 2: <input type=hidden name=id value=5741>
row 3: <input type=hidden name=id value=58741>

Comment: Then, instead of setting the value to the row index for selected rows, you could append something to the existing value, like: `|s` if the row is selected. On the server side, you could check each value for the suffix.

Comment: thx for the response. but this |s value for me here is not a set value. just like the example i provided above, each row has its own value. what needs to change to catch those value?